# Ayuda con input de tipo date HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Buen dia, tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
var fecha = new Date();
        var anio = fecha.getFullYear();
        var dia = fecha.getDate();
        var _mes = fecha.getMonth();//viene con valores de 0 al 11
        _mes = _mes + 1;//ahora lo tienes de 1 al 12
        if (_mes < 10)//ahora le agregas un 0 para el formato date
        { var mes = "0" + _mes;}
        else
        { var mes = _mes.toString;}
        document.getElementById("fechaCita").min = anio+'-'+mes+'-'+dia;
```

El cual corresponde al siguiente input:

```
<input type="date" name="fechaCita" id="fechaCita" class="form-control required" min="2017-01-01">
```

Lo que estoy intentando realizar es lo siguiente, de momento así como esta valida que no se pueda seleccionar días anteriores, y eso esta muy bien, sin embargo necesito que no se puedan seleccionar los días domingo y que se pueda seleccionar a partir de 48 horas en delante (2 días), por ej. tomamos la fecha correspondiente al dia de ahora, para poder agendar una cita, no se puede seleccionar este mismo dia y tampoco mañana, únicamente a partir de pasado mañana.

Espero haber podido explicarme bien, agradezco la ayuda, saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obtener el día de la semana necesitas la función getDay: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp

Así que en tu caso sería, por ejemplo:

```
var semana = fecha.getDay();
```

Entonces puedes aplicar un control, si semana == 0 (0 sería domingo), que la fecha en cuestión no sea valida

Para el resto he creado una función que lo controla, devuelve true si la fecha es valida (fecha futura, +2 dias y que no sea domingo) y false si no lo es. Espero que te sirva :)

*(Edito para arreglar un par de errores, y también he añadido una validación para que salte el error del input si se introduce domingo.. antes solo tenía controlado el domingo en la suma respecto a la fecha actual)*

```
//fecha actual
var fecha = new Date();
var anio = fecha.getFullYear();
var dia = fecha.getDate();
var _mes = fecha.getMonth();
if (_mes < 10){ var mes = "0" + _mes;}else{ var mes = _mes.toString;}

var fecha_futura = "2020-09-03" //año mes día

function validarFecha(fecha_futura,dia,_mes,anio) {

    //lo modifico porque la fecha_input del input sale en formato YYYY-MM-DD
    var f = fecha_futura.split("-");
    var dia_futura = parseInt(f[2]);
    var mes_futura = parseInt(f[1])-1;
    var anio_futura = parseInt(f[0]);
    
    //que no seleccione fechas anteriores a la fecha actual
    if(anio_futura < anio) {
        return false;
    } else if(anio_futura == anio) {
        if(mes_futura < _mes) {
            return false;
        } else if(mes_futura == _mes) {
            if(dia_futura<dia) {
                return false;
            } 
        } 
    }
    
    //validar que la fecha_futura introducida no sea domingo
    var fecha_f = new Date(anio_futura,mes_futura,dia_futura);
    var semana_f = fecha_f.getDay();
    if(semana_f == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    
    //sumamos dos días a la fecha actual, al hacer la suma en el objeto siempre sale una fecha valida
    var d = dia + 2;
    var fecha2 = new Date(anio,_mes,d);
    
    //comprobamos que no sea domingo, en caso de serlo sumamos 1 día más
    if(fecha2.getDay == 0) {
        d = d + 1;
        var fecha2 = new Date(anio,_mes,d);
    }
    
    //y la fecha futura tiene que ser igual o superior a fecha2
    var dia2 = fecha2.getDate();
    var _mes2 = fecha2.getMonth();
     if (_mes2 < 10)
    { var _mes2 = "0" + _mes2;}
    else
    { var _mes2 = _mes2.toString;}
    var anio2 = fecha2.getFullYear();

    if(anio_futura < anio2) {
        return false;
    } else if(anio_futura == anio2) {
        if(mes_futura < _mes2) {
            return false;
        } else if(mes_futura == _mes2) {
            if(dia_futura<dia2) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

validarFecha(fecha_futura,dia,_mes,anio);
```

Y esta página web puede tener información útil: https://programarfacil.com/tutoriales/fragmentos/javascript/comparar-fechas-en-javascript/

---

En respuesta al comentario:

```
//evento que se ejecuta al modificar el input
document.getElementById('fechaCita').addEventListener('change', function() {

//recojo la fecha introducida en el input
var fecha_input = document.getElementById('fechaCita').value;

//fecha actual
var fecha = new Date();
var anio = fecha.getFullYear();
var dia = fecha.getDate();
var _mes = fecha.getMonth();
if (_mes < 10){ var mes = "0" + _mes;}else{ var mes = _mes.toString;}

if(validarFecha(fecha_input,dia,_mes,anio) == false) {
    alert("Por favor introduce una fecha valida")
}

})
```

Y el código ejecutable: https://jsfiddle.net/by02soav/

Comment: seria tanta molestia que pudieras indicarme como quedaría el HTML, ya que me da error en la variable dia_actual.

Comment: He actualizado la función, arreglando un par de errores, y he añadido al final el código para ejecutarlo en un html. También incluyo un link de jsfiddle con el código

Comment: Agradezco toda la ayuda.